# Perform Drag&Drop with Cypress

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

I've tried for some days to perform an e2e test that performs a Drag&Drop event in Selenium, and after several ways to resolve this, someone told me about Cypress, so, here I am trying to learn this new stuff.

The question is, how could I get the x position and the y position from a certain element with Cypress? In the GitHub issues someone used this function

```
function moveElement(element, x, y) {
        cy.get(`${element}`)
            .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
            .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: x, clientY: y })
            .trigger('mouseup', { force: true })
    }
```

BUT, I dont think that insert the x and y coordinates directly is the best way to work, so, in Selenium I got something like

```
int getXCoordinate(WebElement){
    location = WebElement.getLocation();
    x = location.getX();
    return X;
}
```

Is there any way to code a function similar to this?

**UPDATE**

For those interested in this, cypress runs plain ES6 so you can just use

```
element.left+window.scrollX
```

to retrieve X coordinate and

```
element.top+window.scrollY
```

to retrieve Y coordinate.

Comment: How are you implementing drag and drop in your component?

Comment: I'm using Angular for my website, and I'm using Dragula module to implement that functionality https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what are you exactly trying out but if your goal is to provide a general drag and drop action through Cypress, there is an npm package 
`npm install --save-dev cypress-file-upload`

And you should import it to the cypress command.js

The details are stated at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload and there is also an example with drag and drop there.

An example of how I implemented is:

```
it("should upload a file", () => {
        cy.fixture('afile.withanextension','base64').then(file => {
            cy.get('input') // or how you find that element
                .upload({
                            file,
                            fileName: 'afile.withanextension',
                            mimeType: 'propermimetype' // e.g. image/jpg
                        },
                        {
                            uploadType:'input'
                        }
            )
        });
    })
```